# How to get the type of a list of values from an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this type:

```
type RouteList = 'admin/dashboard' | 'admin/users' | 'admin/roles';
```

How can I create this type above from this array dynamically?

```
const routeList = ['admin/dashboard','admin/users','admin/roles'];
```

Comment: You may prefer opposite action of inferring type from array, it's more simple and stable

Comment: But basically it's called `UnionToTuple` and it has no guarantee on array order

Comment: What do you mean by ‘dynamically’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code :

```js
const routeList = ['admin/dashboard','admin/users','admin/roles'] as const;

type RouteList = typeof routeList[number]
```

Comment: Goodluck my friend

Answer (score -2):

try this code, u can use array includes().

```js
const yourRoute = 'admin/users';
const routeList = ['admin/dashboard','admin/users','admin/roles'];
let isApproved = false;

if (routeList.includes(yourRoute)) {
    isApproved = true;
}

console.log(isApproved);
```